# Sum of Route Times in Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a field in Access that takes the date difference between 2 time values to determine the total route time.  Now I need to add up all the values in that field to determine how many hours:Minutes of route time happened on x date.  This is the code I have to calculate the total route time for each record:

```
Me.tbTotalRouteTime.Value = Format(DateAdd("n", -50, [ReturnTime]) - [DispatchTime], "Short Time")
```

I tried summing it in a field like this:

```
=Sum([TotalRTTime])
```

Now I need to adjust the fomrat, so I tried hhh:nn but it doesn't give me the correct result.  What format do I need to show the exact amount of hours and minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be:

```
Me!tbTotalRouteTime.Value = Format(Sum(DateAdd("n", -50, [ReturnTime]) - [DispatchTime]), "h:nn")
```

If you will sum to 24 hours or more, a custom function is needed, like:

```
Public Function FormatHourMinute( _
  ByVal datTime As Date, _
  Optional ByVal strSeparator As String = ":") _
  As String

' Returns count of days, hours and minutes of datTime
' converted to hours and minutes as a formatted string
' with an optional choice of time separator.
'
' Example:
'   datTime: #10:03# + #20:01#
'   returns: 30:04
'
' 2005-02-05. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim strHour       As String
  Dim strMinute     As String
  Dim strHourMinute As String

  strHour = CStr(Fix(datTime) * 24 + Hour(datTime))
  ' Add leading zero to minute count when needed.
  strMinute = Right("0" & CStr(Minute(datTime)), 2)
  strHourMinute = strHour & strSeparator & strMinute

  FormatHourMinute = strHourMinute

End Function
```

Comment: It will be to 24 hours or more.  Do you know how to do that? I know how to create a custom function but not how to make it show more than 24 hours?

Comment: Yes, I've added it to the answer.